# 403 Forbidden Error while sending data to server using post method in firefox-addon-sdk

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, http-status-code-403

I am trying to build a Firefox Addon. In this addon I have to send some data to my server when user clicks on a button.

Here is my code to send the data using post method

```
fosterzen.port.on("bookmark", function (text) {

var test=encodeURI("text");
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;
Request({
  url: "http://myserver.com/FirefoxExtension/submit.php",
  content: {q: test},
  onComplete: function (response) {
    console.log('Success: '+response.text);
  }
 }).post();


 fosterzen.hide();
 });
```

But I am getting 403 Forbidden error message "You dont have permission to access FirefoxExtension/submit.php on this server".

I even tried by changing the permission of file and folder. But still getting the same error. I want to know why I am getting this error and what should I do to fix it?

P.S :  I have already developed Google Chrome Extension. And I am able to post data to the same page through google chrome extension. But through Firefox Extension, its giving 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: This question is likely more suited for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/), as this is a problem with your server configuration, apparently. As such, without knowing your configuration (or even your software), it is highly unlikely that somebody will be able to answer you.

Comment: I dont think its about server configuration. I have already developed Google Chrome Extension. And I am able to post data to the same page through google chrome extension. But through Firefox Extension, its giving 403 Forbidden error. So I think its something related to Firefox Extension.